# Netsuite Credit Card Payment via Suitelet

Tags: netsuite

I need to create a suitelet which can be used for credit card payment for Invoices.
I should be able to send the url for the suitelet in an email to the user, so that user can pay without logging into netsuite.
Is there any solution for this except the paid suiteapps ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad idea. Just because a Suitelet is called via HTTPS, that does not mean it is PCI compliant.

I would not do this under any circumstance.

I would look for a SuiteApp or other means to accept a payment that is secure and PCI compliant.